# During deployment: 500 - The request timed out when installing dependencies

Tags: typescript, npm, deployment, azure-web-app-service, botframework

I'm trying to deploy my bot to Azure. So I ran the following command:

> az bot publish --name  --proj-name "" --resource-group  --code-dir "/path/to/my-app" --verbose --version v4

But it times out (I removed my project name and username for security reasons):

> Configured default '' for arg resource_group_name
>
> Detected SDK version v4. Running prepare publish in code directory
>
> /Users//Documents/GitHub// and for project file
>
> Preparing Bot Builder SDK v4 bot for publish, with code directory
>
> /Users//Documents/GitHub// and project file .
>
> Detected bot language Node, Bot Builder version v4.
>
> Creating upload zip file.
>
> Creating upload zip file, code directory
>
> /Users//Documents/GitHub//.
>
> Adding node_modules to folders to exclude from zip file.
>
> Compressing bot source into 
>   /Users//Documents/GitHub//upload.zip.
>
> Zip file path created, at 
>   /Users//Documents/GitHub//upload.zip.
>
> Emptying the "site/wwwroot/" folder on Kudu in preparation for 
>   publishing.
>
> "site/wwwroot/" successfully emptied.
>
> Source code read, uploading to Kudu.
>
> Source code successfully uploaded.
>
> Retrieving the latest deployment info.
>
> Bot source published. Preparing bot application to run the new source.
>
> Detected language javascript. Installing node dependencies in remote bot.

Then here's the error:

> Failed with status code 500 and reason 500 - The 
>   request timed out.
>
> ### 500 - The request timed out.
>
> The web server failed to respond within the specified time.

```
"dependencies": {
    "botbuilder": "^4.2.0",
    "botbuilder-ai": "^4.2.0",
    "botframework-config": "^4.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "flex-menu": "git+https://yousef-shanawany-flex@dev.azure.com/yousef-shanawany-flex/flex-menu/_git/flex-menu",
    "replace": "^1.0.0",
    "restify": "^7.2.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/dotenv": "6.1.0",
    "@types/restify": "7.2.6",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.7",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah so this is a known issue with the `az bot publish` command right now. Unfortunately it performs some proprietary deployment steps which make it behave differently from a typical web application deployment on Azure. Specifically, at the point when you're getting the error, it's executing the `npm install` command via Kudu and it's just taking too long for that command to finish and, therefore, it times out causing the `500` error. The team is aware of this and will be working to improve the experience.

My recommendation, for now, would be to set up and use [the local git deploy method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git). That is the simplest approach that requires no other services to get going. If your project is already up in a remote git repo in Azure DevOps/GitHub/GitLab/BitBucket/etc, you might want to consider using [the Continuous Deployment support for those](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment) instead which will light up CD for all the contributors on your team. Either of these approaches will trigger [the "standard" Kudu deployment process for web applications](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) which you can read all about here if you ever needed to further [customize](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments).

Comment: I tried it but Azure shell gave me an error message. I submitted an issue for it [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24218).